# Oracle query: how do I limit the returned records to only those having a count > 1 but show full results?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, toad

I need to show all the users who have more than one ID but not return the users who do. I tried group by having but I need to list the IDs and not just count them so could not get that to work for me. I ended up with using a the code below but it returns all the records.

select id,fname,lname,ssn,dob
count(id) over partition by fname,lname,ssn,dob) as cnt
from TABLE
order by cnt desc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select id, fname, lname, ssn, dob
from (select id, fname, lname, ssn, dob,
             count(id) over (partition by fname, lname, ssn, dob) as cnt
      from TABLE
     ) t
where cnt >= 2
order by cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE (FNAME, LNAME, TALLY) AS
(
  SELECT FNAME, LNAME, COUNT(ID) AS TALLY
  FROM TABLE
  HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
)
SELECT T.ID, C.FNAME,C.LNAME FROM CTE C
JOIN TABLE T
ON C.FNAME = T.FNAME
AND C.LNAME = T.LNAME
```